# "Twixtor" ? Any open source equivalent for Ubuntu Linux?

Tags: software-recommendation, video, video-editor

I am looking for something like "Twixtor" / Slow motion / photomorph. Is there any open source equivalent for Ubuntu Linux?

Here are some video samples showing this effect:

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=--ZwS0bihHQ
- http://vimeo.com/21050859

Answer (score 5):

Have a look at

> [SlowmoVideo](http://slowmovideo.granjow.net/)

slowmoVideo is an OpenSource program that creates slow-motion videos from your footage.

But it does not simply make your videos play at 0.01× speed. You can smoothly slow down and speed up your footage, optionally with motion blur.

How does slow motion work? slowmoVideo tries to find out where pixels move in the video (this information is called Optical Flow), and then uses this information to calculate the additional frames.

[image]

[The download page also includes .DEBs](http://slowmovideo.granjow.net/download.php) for 12.10 and 12.04.